# Help to make braces in array with sidenote type detail

Tags: tables

I am trying to make an array like this with the braces two lines long with details like a sidenote.
[image]

I tried:

```
\begin{array}{c}    
\sin&\leftrightarrow&\tanh\\
\cos&\leftrightarrow&\sech\\    
\end{array}
```

After adding the braces it looks like:

```
\begin{array}{c}    
\left.
\sin&\leftrightarrow&\tanh\\
\cos&\leftrightarrow&\sech\\   
\right\} 
\end{array}
```

It works fine but adding braces doesn't seems to work. Any help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`. As well, you say that "adding braces doesn't seem to work" but your code shows no braces, where are they?

Comment: You can use the `blkarray` package for that.

Comment: @yo' It's edited

Comment: Well, you need ```\}``` rather than `}`. However, it is not a _minimal (non-)working example. Have you [**clicked the link**](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) in my previous comment at all?

Comment: It should be `\left.\begin{array}{ccc}` and `\end{array}
\right\}` and also how do you compile `\sech`?

Comment: @HarishKumar sech isn't a problem for a while

Comment: @yo' actually i'm using it over SE network .I suppose those things are embedded and I start writing form $$..$$

Comment: @ADG Ah ok so it's the browser thingy, MathJaX?

Comment: @yo' yes, for that what should I mention in my questions from now on?

Comment: @ADG Well, the problem is that MathJaX questions are off-topic here _unless they apply to LaTeX as well._ So your question is not off-topic because the solution before seems to work in both LaTeX and MathJaX. But it's considered somewhat borderline.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
  \[
  \begin{gathered}
  \left.\begin{array}{c@{\,\,}c@{\,\,}c}
\sin&\leftrightarrow&\tanh\\
\cos&\leftrightarrow&\sec
\end{array}
\right\}
  \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1     \\  %% second line
  \left.\begin{array}{c@{\,\,}c@{\,\,}c}
\sin&\leftrightarrow&\tanh\\
\cos&\leftrightarrow&\sec
\end{array}
\right\}
  \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1
  \end{gathered}
  \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Just for variety, here's a solution that uses the `drcases` environment of the `mathtools` package.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator\sech{sech}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
\begin{drcases}
\sin \leftrightarrow \tanh\\
\cos \leftrightarrow \sec
\end{drcases}
&\quad \sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1; \quad \tanh^2 x + \sech^2 x = 1\\
\begin{drcases}
\tan \leftrightarrow \sinh\\
\sec \leftrightarrow \cosh
\end{drcases}
&\quad \sec^2 x - \tan^2 x = 1; \quad \cosh^2 x - \sinh^2 x = 1
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

Two other solutions: one with the `blkarray` package, the other with the `rcases` environment, from `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass[112pt]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[showframe, nomarginpar, textwidth = 15cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{blkarray}
\usepackage{nccmath}

\DeclareMathOperator\sech{sech}
\DeclareMathOperator\csch{csch}

    \begin{document}
\leavevmode\vskip 1cm
    \begin{equation*}
\renewcommand\arraystretch{1.333}
\hskip-19em\begin{blockarray}{r@{{}\longleftrightarrow{}}l}
    \begin{block}{r@{{}\longleftrightarrow {}}l\Right{\}}{\ $ \sin² x + \cos² x = 1; \enspace \tanh² x + \sech² x = 1$}}%
    \sin & \tanh \\
      \cos & \sech \\
    \end{block}
%
 \begin{block}{r@{{}\longleftrightarrow {}}l\Right{\}}{\ $ \sec² x - \tan² x = 1; \enspace \cosh² - \sinh² x = 1$}}%
 \tan & \sinh \\
 \sec & \cosh \\
\end{block}%
 \begin{block}{r@{{}\longleftrightarrow {}}l\Right{\}}{\ $ \csc² x - \cot² x = 1; \enspace \coth² - \csch² x = 1$}}
 \csc & \coth \\
 \cot & \csch\\
\end{blockarray}
\end{equation*}

\begin{align*}
\begin{rcases}
\sin \longleftrightarrow \tanh \\
\cos \longleftrightarrow \sech
\end{rcases} &\ \sin² x + \cos² x = 1; \enspace \tanh² x + \sech² x = 1\\[-0.5ex]
%
 \begin{rcases}
 \tan \longleftrightarrow \sinh \\
 \sec \longleftrightarrow\cosh
\end{rcases} &\ \sec² x - \tan² x = 1; \enspace \cosh² - \sinh² x = 1\\[-0.5ex]
%
 \begin{rcases}
 \csc \longleftrightarrow \coth \\
 \cot \longleftrightarrow \coth
    \end{rcases} &\ \csc² x - \cot² x = 1; \enspace \coth² - \csch² x = 1
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

[image]